# Use function declaration passed as an argument

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a stub definition that the code below could use:

```js
func.calc({
  'divide': function(num1, num2) {
    // do something
  },
  'add': function(num1, num2, num3) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

So far, I've been having trouble getting the parameters passed to the functions in the second argument. Here's what I've been trying to do:

```js
var func = {
  calc: function(operationsArray) {
    if (div) {
      operationsArray[0](args); /* get args */
    }
    else (add) {
      operationsArray[1](args); /* get args */
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the whole function definition (with parameters and implementation) when it is passed as a parameter like in the first snippet?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do based on the pseudo-code you've provided.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. Your example code is too abstract to understand, and has syntax errors anyway. Try a real [mcve]

Comment: Re edit: Click "Run code snippet". You have basic syntax errors!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I'm trying to do is create a stub declaration for the code, so the assumption is that all I can edit is the declaration (second snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `func.temp` as method that accepts an `Array` as second argument. On the other hand, you call the method with an `Object` as the second argument.

JavaScript specification tells us that field order is not guaranteed:

> 4.3.3 Object
>   An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

meaning you shouldn't access `in_func` & `in_func2` using location index (i.e. [0]).

**You should either call the function with an array like this:**

```js
func.temp(mainArg, [
  function(arg1, arg2) {
    // do something
  },
  function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    // do something
  }
]);
```

***OR*, implement the function so that it uses explicit names:**

```js
var func = {
  temp: function(arg1, func_obj) {
    // do something with arg1
    if (trigger1) {
      func_obj.in_func(/* get params */);
    }
    else (trigger2) {
      func_obj.in_func2(/* get params */);
    }
  }
}
```